# Web: How do we display content on the Client after making a slow Server Side Call?

Tags: javascript, json, web

I am working on a Web Application for which I am currently doing something like this:

Page1.php posts to Page2.php.

Page2.php contains an HTML file with 2 Javascript files. The first Javascript file uses an AJAX call to trigger Page3.php. The second Javascript file listens to Result.json for results.

Page3.php invokes a Python Script, Task.py.

Task.py takes about 15 minutes to run, writes results to Result.json which I need to display on Page2.php.

1. The problem here is 1st that the since Task.py is such an expensive call, I end up on Page2.php on Chrome and Chrome pops open the window asking me if I would like to kill or wait for the page to load and the Web Page eventually becomes unresponsive (Times Out).

As a result, I become unable to display the results stored in Result.json on the page.

2. Another problem that I am having is that the Task.py file that I am executing appears to be a blocking call, so when my first Javascript makes the AJAX call, it prevents my 2nd Javascript from listening to Result.json for results (When Javascript makes an AJAX call, it waits there until it gets the response back). So even if there was content already in the Json file, it wouldn't pick up on it until the 1st AJAX call returns.

The Listening Javascript file looks something like this:

```
 while(true){
    result = setTimeout(myFunction, 60000);

    if(result === true){
        console.log("Quitting the loop");
        break;
    }
}
```

where myFunction parses the Json file and manipulates the DOM to display the content.

Any Advice?

Comment: use a web-worker and an async callback - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 1):

You can use Server Push/Websocket for it. If your server is ready to serve the data, it can notify the client side to get the data. Just search for socket.io / nodejs.

first Ajax call starts page3 and set event listener to server push message. If it receives the message, simply get content of Result.json.

Comment: This was one of the solutions that I have considered. Another solution is to implement some sort of Background Queue on the Server to run the expensive call in the Background. But the problem is that I need to wait for the results of the background queue in order for me to display it on the UI.

Comment: This solution seems a bit complex (to use Web Sockets for this). Is there a simpler solution to display content after an expensive Server Side Call?

Comment: why not use an asynchronous callback?

Comment: How does that solve the Chrome page timing out and becoming unresponsive?

Comment: it's timing out because you're using while(true) in an event driven loop.

Comment: This is one possible case of time out. However, even if I take out the listening script, what is happening is that it will still time out on the expensive AJAX call to trigger the script. So we are still dealing with the same issue. Im not sure an Async call can fix this? Feel free to prove me wrong. Async callback is a good idea though.

Comment: change the timeout parameter in your ajax code; may i ask what the script is doing that it takes ~15mins?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89481/discussion-between-simonzhu-and-data).

Comment: How does changing the timeout parameter in your ajax code prevent chrome from killing your page?